# Link to Google search throws bad request (400) in IE

Tags: c#, html, model-view-controller

I'm developing a C# MVC web-application where I'd like to directly link to a google search with a specific string. The final string is formatted in the following way: http://www.google.com/search?q=partialstring1+partialstring2+partialstring3

The html code looks as follows:

```
<p><br><a target="_blank" href=http://www.google.com/search?q=' + FormattedString + '> Google </a> ' + </p>
```

This html is again part of a final string which is should be called in an InfoBubble.
It works on any other browser (Firefox, Chrome, Opera ...) but it results in Error 400 when opening the link in Internet Explorer (11 and below).

It says *Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request*.

It works when I look up the specific string directly in Google and the resulting url looks exactly the same as the one I'd like to open from my application.
The formatted string gets rid of all umlauts (ä, ü, ö) and special characters (%&/§$) and works fine in Firefox when I copy and paste it there.

Is there some special IE-formatting for Google searches? I really don't know how to fix this issue, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any issue with loading the link in IE 11 at least.  I have it setup like this with Razor formatting.  Are you using something different for the views?

```
@{
    var FormattedString = "partialstring1+partialstring2+partialstring3";
}

<p><br><a target="_blank" href="http://www.google.com/search?q=@FormattedString"> Google </a></p>
```

Which gives me a functional link in any browser.

Comment: I've found the solution to this issue: After copy and paste it into notepad++ i figured out that IE inserts an unknown character (RS) into the formatted string, which resulted in a bad request.